# TObjectList appear in two units

Tags: delphi, delphi-xe3

I am using Delphi XE3. When searching helps for TObjectList, I find it appears in two units:

http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/Tokyo/en/System.Contnrs.TObjectList

and

http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/Tokyo/en/System.Generics.Collections.TObjectList

In such a case, which unit should I include to use the class? Also what is the different between TObjectList and TList, I just see TObjectList = class(TList) in the first document so TObjectList is identical to TList?

Thanks

Comment: One is generic, and one is not. `TObjectList = class(TList)` means that `TObjectList` inherits from `TList`, not that it is identical. Closer inspection of the documentation is needed.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`System.Contnrs.TObjectList` is the older legacy non-Generic version of a list of objects.

`System.Generics.Collections.TObjectList<T>` is the newer Generic version.

See [Overview of Generics](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/Tokyo/en/Overview_of_Generics).

Use whichever one suits your needs.

The non-Generic `TList` is just a list of raw pointers. It does not do anything special with the pointers that are stored in it.

The non-Generic `TObjectList` is *derived* from `TList` to add extra handling of general purpose `TObject` pointers, such as to add the `OwnsObjects` property which allows the list to free stored objects when the list itself is freed.

The Generic `TList<T>` is similar to, but not derived from, the non-Generic `TList`, where `T` can be *any* type, it does not even need to be a pointer (for example, `TList<Integer>`).

The Generic `TObjectList<T>` is similar to, but not derived from, the non-Generic `TObjectList`, where `T` can be any class type that is derived from `TObject`.

Comment: Thank you very much. I have two more questions: 1. Is Generics similar to that of class template in C++? 2. Which version of Delphi starts support Generics?

Comment: @alancc 1. Similar, yes, but also not quite as flexible/powerful as templates. There are a lot of things you can do in templates but not in Generics. 2. D2007 for .NET, D2009 for other platforms.